# Data doesn't pass through the database when "CuteEditor" is used in XML Form Configuration

Tags: vb.net, xml-configuration, posting, xml-formatting

I have a vb app that uses configuration files to save data into the database. It's using an editor called "CuteEditor".

Below is what I have for config.

```
<Fields>
    <Control>CuteEditor</Control>
    <Required>No</Required>
    <Order>17</Order>
    <Label>Main Content</Label>
    <Id>ContentText</Id>
    <Text />
</Fields>
```

Edit statement in Config.

```
<sqlUpdate>
DECLARE @id int
UPDATE table SET    
    ContentText = @ContentText,
WHERE ContentId = @ContentId
</sqlupdate>
```

When I change the control from "CuteEditor" to "Multiline", it works perfectly fine (Saves the content). But when it's CuteEditor, it doesn't.

My guess is the content should be changed to html format. (Just an idea)

[view of CuteEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXT9k.png)

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Is that [Cute Editor for ASP.NET](https://cutesoft.net/)? And is "Multiline" an HTML `<textarea>`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hey, yes, it's Cute Editor for ASP.NET. For "Multiline", I tried to put "<Control>Multiline</Control>" instead of "<Control>CuteEditor</Control>" and the content was saved to the database.

Comment: 1) Does "save data into the database" refer to data which is entered into the `<Control>`? 2) Is this an app which you have written?